# Is it okay to observe Notification Center with async sequence from init (async await)?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, async-await

I want to observe `.EKEventStoreChanged` notifications from `NotificationCenter` with async wait APIs, which means processing the Async Sequence.

This code works, but I'm unsure if creating the Task (and thus observing the changes) in the `init()` is a good idea or if there are better options. I'm a bit worried that this is a misuse of the `init()` because right now, if I see it correctly, the `init()` has to run the entire lifetime of the `ObservableObject` but inits are intended to just run during object creation?

```
class CalendarState: ObservableObject {
    // ...
    
    init() {
       // ...
        
        Task{
            await observeCalendar()
        }
    }

    func observeCalendar() async {
        for await _ in NotificationCenter.default.notifications(named: .EKEventStoreChanged) {
            await loadEvents(date: date)
    }
}
```

Any help, tips or experiences are welcome - thanks :D

Comment: Looks like you know the answer :)

Comment: Alright, thanks @Asperi :D Any idea for a better place to call observeCalendar()? It should be observing the entire lifetime

Comment: In my opinion, this is an abomination. A better option would be to use the NotificationCenter's publisher to process, potentially, multiple events.

Comment: Doing a task does not seems very good : you could add the class as observer or create a publisher.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! Are there specific reasons why using a Task is not a good idea here? I've tried to get along without Combine and thought utilizing the new async apis would be a great fit :D

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using the `notifications` asynchronous sequence. (They put it there for a reason. Lol.) The issue with `Task`, though, is that you are opting out of structured concurrency and therefore must `cancel` it yourself manually.

Answer (score 11):

In SwiftUI, the [`.task`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/button/task(priority:_:)) modifier will cancel automatically when the view is removed. Therefore, because of structured concurrency, the `AsyncSequence` of the notifications will be canceled for you, too:

```swift
struct DetailsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button("Dismiss") {
            ...
        }
        .task {
            await addNotificationsHandler()
        }
    }

    func addNotificationsHandler() async {
        for await notification in NotificationCenter.default.notifications(named: .foo) {
            foo(with: notification)
        }
    }
}
```

---

In UIKit, you have to be more careful because asynchronous sequences are not canceled automatically. So, you would keep track of the `Task` for that `AsyncSequence` and `cancel` it when the view disappears:

```swift
private var notificationsTask: Task<(), Never>?

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    notificationsTask = Task {
        await addNotificationsHandler()
    }
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

    notificationsTask?.cancel()
}

func addNotificationsHandler() async {
    for await notification in NotificationCenter.default.notifications(named: .foo) {
        foo(with: notification)
    }
}
```

Bottom line, in the above UIKit example, you have to manually cancel the `Task` in which you are looping through the `AsyncSequence`. In SwiftUI, the `.task` modifier is canceled for you, and therefore the `AsyncSequence` will be canceled automatically.

Bottom line, if you start looping through an `AsyncSequence` within a `Task`, then make sure to `cancel` that `Task` when you are done. By definition, `Task` opts out of structured concurrency and you, therefore, have to handle the cancelation yourself.

---

If you have multiple notifications that you want to observe, you can use a task group. E.g., in SwiftUI, here is an example observing when the app resigns active and when it becomes active:

```swift
struct SampleView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = SampleViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack { … }
        .task {
            await viewModel.addNotificationsHandlers()
        }
    }
}

@MainActor
class SampleViewModel: ObservableObject {
    func addNotificationsHandlers() async {
        await withTaskGroup(of: Void.self) { group in
            group.addTask { await self.addBecomeActiveHandler() }
            group.addTask { await self.addResignActiveHandler() }
        }
    }

    func addBecomeActiveHandler() async {
        for await notification in NotificationCenter.default.notifications(named: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification) {
            handleBecomeActive(for: notification)
        }
    }

    func addResignActiveHandler() async {
        for await notification in NotificationCenter.default.notifications(named: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification) {
            handleResignActive(for: notification)
        }
    }

    func handleBecomeActive(for notification: Notification) { … }

    func handleResignActive(for notification: Notification) { … }
}
```

Or in UIKit:

```swift
private var notificationsTask: Task<(), Never>?

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    addNotificationsHandlers()
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

    removeNotificationsHandlers()
}

func addNotificationsHandlers() {
    notificationsTask = Task {
        await withTaskGroup(of: Void.self) { group in
            group.addTask { await self.addBecomeActiveHandler() }
            group.addTask { await self.addResignActiveHandler() }
        }
    }
}

func removeNotificationsHandlers() {
    notificationsTask?.cancel()
}

func addBecomeActiveHandler() async {
    for await notification in NotificationCenter.default.notifications(named: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification) {
        handleBecomeActive(for: notification)
    }
}

func addResignActiveHandler() async {
    for await notification in NotificationCenter.default.notifications(named: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification) {
        handleResignActive(for: notification)
    }
}

func handleBecomeActive(for notification: Notification) { … }

func handleResignActive(for notification: Notification) { … }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Rob! Glad to hear that the approach of using notifications asynchronous sequence is valid — I'm using SwiftUI so the Task is automatically canceled. I've already tried to use the `.task` Modifier on a view, but I'm building a menu bar app for macOS which should start listening to Notifications without any view necessarily being drawn (which means the `.task{...}` is not started) — that's why I came up with the idea of calling the function it in `init()`. Any ideas where I could start calling the function to listen for notifications during the entire app lifetime?

Comment: I don’t know the lifecycle of menubar apps well enough to answer that question, but I’m surprised that `.task` wouldn’t work.

Comment: @Rob Unless I'm mistaken, in `UIKit` you'd need multiple `Task`s and  `async` functions to observe multiple notification async sequences. 

For example, if you wanted to observe notifications for `UIScene.didEnterBackgroundNotification` you couldn't add another `for await` in `addNotificationsHandler()` because it can only monitor the `for await ... foo` sequence?

Comment: @StuartBreckenridge - I've updated my answer showing how you can have multiple asynchronous sequences. Note, you could have multiple `Task` objects, but I prefer to use task group (that way, when we cancel the notifications task, all of the `notifications` sequences will be canceled automatically.